# What names can be used in plt.cm.get_cmap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-analysis, matplotlib-basemap

I have this code :

```
plt.scatter(data_projected[:,0],data_projected[:,1],c=digits.target
        ,edgecolors='none',alpha=0.5,cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('nipy_spectral',10));
```

My confusion comes from **plt.cm.get_cmap('nipy_spectral',10)**. Sometimes there will be **plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')** instead.

Is the `'RdYlBu'`,`'nipy_spectral'` the name of a color? And is there any other names to use instead?

Is there a list of all colors available?

I have read [the document](http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html) but it does not seem to help or I do not understand it.

Comment: `plt.cm.datad.keys()` yields all the colormap names.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first argument to `plt.cm.get_cmap('nipy_spectral',10)` is the name of a colormap. You can get a list of all available colormaps via

```
import matplotlib.cm
print(matplotlib.cm.cmap_d.keys())
```

or you may have a look at the [colormap reference](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html).

Comment: It's work!!! thanks
and i have got something else help in http://matplotlib.org/2.1.0/api/pyplot_summary.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colormaps

Comment: Unfortunately, in matplotlib version 3.3.1 I get `MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The global colormaps dictionary is no longer considered public API.` when I try to read `matplotlib.cm.cmap_d`

Answer (score 5):

As of matplotlib >= 1.5.0, an approach is to call the [higher-level `matplotlib.pyplot.colormaps()` getter function](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_summary.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colormaps) rather than directly accessing lower-level data structures (e.g., `matplotlib.cm.cmap_d`, `matplotlib.cm.datad`).

Calling `matplotlib.pyplot.colormaps()` has the advantage of implicitly sorting the names of all returned colormaps (in lexicographic order). Since `matplotlib.cm.cmap_d` is currently implemented as a standard unordered dictionary, printing or iterating over its keys as in [ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47302961/2809027) a bit more cumbersome to read: e.g.,

```
# The pyplot.colormap() approach (works with matplotlib >= 1.5.0 ).
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> print(plt.colormaps())
['Accent', 'Accent_r', 'Blues', 'Blues_r', 'BrBG', 'BrBG_r', 'BuGn', 'BuGn_r', 'BuPu', 'BuPu_r', 'CMRmap', 'CMRmap_r', 'Dark2', 'Dark2_r', 'GnBu', 'GnBu_r', 'Greens', 'Greens_r', 'Greys', 'Greys_r', 'OrRd', 'OrRd_r', 'Oranges', 'Oranges_r', 'PRGn', 'PRGn_r', 'Paired', 'Paired_r', 'Pastel1', 'Pastel1_r', 'Pastel2', 'Pastel2_r', 'PiYG', 'PiYG_r', 'PuBu', 'PuBuGn', 'PuBuGn_r', 'PuBu_r', 'PuOr', 'PuOr_r', 'PuRd', 'PuRd_r', 'Purples', 'Purples_r', 'RdBu', 'RdBu_r', 'RdGy', 'RdGy_r', 'RdPu', 'RdPu_r', 'RdYlBu', 'RdYlBu_r', 'RdYlGn', 'RdYlGn_r', 'Reds', 'Reds_r', 'Set1', 'Set1_r', 'Set2', 'Set2_r', 'Set3', 'Set3_r', 'Spectral', 'Spectral_r', 'Wistia', 'Wistia_r', 'YlGn', 'YlGnBu', 'YlGnBu_r', 'YlGn_r', 'YlOrBr', 'YlOrBr_r', 'YlOrRd', 'YlOrRd_r', 'afmhot', 'afmhot_r', 'autumn', 'autumn_r', 'binary', 'binary_r', 'bone', 'bone_r', 'brg', 'brg_r', 'bwr', 'bwr_r', 'cividis', 'cividis_r', 'cool', 'cool_r', 'coolwarm', 'coolwarm_r', 'copper', 'copper_r', 'cubehelix', 'cubehelix_r', 'flag', 'flag_r', 'gist_earth', 'gist_earth_r', 'gist_gray', 'gist_gray_r', 'gist_heat', 'gist_heat_r', 'gist_ncar', 'gist_ncar_r', 'gist_rainbow', 'gist_rainbow_r', 'gist_stern', 'gist_stern_r', 'gist_yarg', 'gist_yarg_r', 'gnuplot', 'gnuplot2', 'gnuplot2_r', 'gnuplot_r', 'gray', 'gray_r', 'hot', 'hot_r', 'hsv', 'hsv_r', 'inferno', 'inferno_r', 'jet', 'jet_r', 'magma', 'magma_r', 'nipy_spectral', 'nipy_spectral_r', 'ocean', 'ocean_r', 'pink', 'pink_r', 'plasma', 'plasma_r', 'prism', 'prism_r', 'rainbow', 'rainbow_r', 'seismic', 'seismic_r', 'spring', 'spring_r', 'summer', 'summer_r', 'tab10', 'tab10_r', 'tab20', 'tab20_r', 'tab20b', 'tab20b_r', 'tab20c', 'tab20c_r', 'terrain', 'terrain_r', 'viridis', 'viridis_r', 'winter', 'winter_r']

# The direct matplotlib.cm approach (also works with matplotlib < 1.5.0)
>>> import matplotlib.cm
>>> print(matplotlib.cm.cmap_d.keys())
dict_keys(['Blues', 'BrBG', 'BuGn', 'BuPu', 'CMRmap', 'GnBu', 'Greens', 'Greys', 'OrRd', 'Oranges', 'PRGn', 'PiYG', 'PuBu', 'PuBuGn', 'PuOr', 'PuRd', 'Purples', 'RdBu', 'RdGy', 'RdPu', 'RdYlBu', 'RdYlGn', 'Reds', 'Spectral', 'Wistia', 'YlGn', 'YlGnBu', 'YlOrBr', 'YlOrRd', 'afmhot', 'autumn', 'binary', 'bone', 'brg', 'bwr', 'cool', 'coolwarm', 'copper', 'cubehelix', 'flag', 'gist_earth', 'gist_gray', 'gist_heat', 'gist_ncar', 'gist_rainbow', 'gist_stern', 'gist_yarg', 'gnuplot', 'gnuplot2', 'gray', 'hot', 'hsv', 'jet', 'nipy_spectral', 'ocean', 'pink', 'prism', 'rainbow', 'seismic', 'spring', 'summer', 'terrain', 'winter', 'Accent', 'Dark2', 'Paired', 'Pastel1', 'Pastel2', 'Set1', 'Set2', 'Set3', 'tab10', 'tab20', 'tab20b', 'tab20c', 'Blues_r', 'BrBG_r', 'BuGn_r', 'BuPu_r', 'CMRmap_r', 'GnBu_r', 'Greens_r', 'Greys_r', 'OrRd_r', 'Oranges_r', 'PRGn_r', 'PiYG_r', 'PuBu_r', 'PuBuGn_r', 'PuOr_r', 'PuRd_r', 'Purples_r', 'RdBu_r', 'RdGy_r', 'RdPu_r', 'RdYlBu_r', 'RdYlGn_r', 'Reds_r', 'Spectral_r', 'Wistia_r', 'YlGn_r', 'YlGnBu_r', 'YlOrBr_r', 'YlOrRd_r', 'afmhot_r', 'autumn_r', 'binary_r', 'bone_r', 'brg_r', 'bwr_r', 'cool_r', 'coolwarm_r', 'copper_r', 'cubehelix_r', 'flag_r', 'gist_earth_r', 'gist_gray_r', 'gist_heat_r', 'gist_ncar_r', 'gist_rainbow_r', 'gist_stern_r', 'gist_yarg_r', 'gnuplot_r', 'gnuplot2_r', 'gray_r', 'hot_r', 'hsv_r', 'jet_r', 'nipy_spectral_r', 'ocean_r', 'pink_r', 'prism_r', 'rainbow_r', 'seismic_r', 'spring_r', 'summer_r', 'terrain_r', 'winter_r', 'Accent_r', 'Dark2_r', 'Paired_r', 'Pastel1_r', 'Pastel2_r', 'Set1_r', 'Set2_r', 'Set3_r', 'tab10_r', 'tab20_r', 'tab20b_r', 'tab20c_r', 'magma', 'magma_r', 'inferno', 'inferno_r', 'plasma', 'plasma_r', 'viridis', 'viridis_r', 'cividis', 'cividis_r'])
```

***Voilà!*** Sane API **+** human-readability **=** *it is good*.

Comment: Note that `plt.colormaps()` simply returns `sorted(matplotlib.cm.cmap_d)`. Not sure where the information comes from, but from my understanding `cmap_d` is not likely to change in the future. Also, consider that the use of pyplot is often not desired, whereas `matplotlib.cm` is easily importable everywhere.